# how can i get array item on laravel?

Tags: laravel

i have 3 item arrray that's look like this

[image]

i want to get my data as 3 item array, here is my controller

```
 public function editView($crewprogrammemoid){
    $getplacement =  PlacementMemo::where('crewprogrammemo_id', $crewprogrammemoid)->get();
    dd(collect($getplacement);
 }
```

when i'm using this `$getplacement =  PlacementMemo::where('crewprogrammemo_id', $crewprogrammemoid)->first();` i got the exact array, but just one, how can i get the 3 array or 3 collection item?? how do i solve that?

***Edit***

what i want is array like this, and bellow that,

[image]

this is when i use `$getplacement =  PlacementMemo::where('crewprogrammemo_id', $crewprogrammemoid)->first();`, it just 1 array, i would like to have all array but when i use get the looks like in image 1

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. What do you exactly want? you already have the array by `PlacementMemo::where('crewprogrammemo_id', $crewprogrammemoid)->get();`

Comment: i edited my post, what i want is something like that, and i have some array bellow that

Comment: you want to fetch the data of the 3rd array. is that what you are after?

Comment: yeah i want to fetch all of it

Comment: @NajafiMH so i must hard code my array like that?? using ```->get()[2]``` what if there is so much data? i dont want to hardcode my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the last item in the array.

```php
$getplacement =  PlacementMemo::where('crewprogrammemo_id', $crewprogrammemoid)->get()->last();
```

this is all 3 items in array.

```php
$getplacement =  PlacementMemo::where('crewprogrammemo_id', $crewprogrammemoid)->get();
```

Comment: glad to see your comment andy ahaha, what i want is not the last, just want to fetch all of the data

Comment: @Appem you want to fetch 3? `$getplacement =  PlacementMemo::where('crewprogrammemo_id', $crewprogrammemoid)->get();` this is all three yeah?